# (Apparently) not all port forwarding rules working in nested network

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

## Network structure

My home network currently consists of two (nested) LANs: One of the LANs (`LAN A`) is connected to the internet (via a *Telekom Speedport W 723V* router [`Router A`] / DSL). The other one (`LAN B`) is connected to `LAN A` (via an *ASUS DSL-AC87VG* router [`Router B`] / E-WAN).

The described network structure is also explained in [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX2AY.png).

*Why this network structure?* Explaination in the spoiler below:

> The ASUS router mentioned above was installed to improve WiFi performance, but it led to compatibility issues with Telekom IPTV receivers in the network, so the Telekom router had to be installed again. Nevertheless, I connected the ASUS router (as mentioned) to the network with the Telekom router to serve as a WiFi access point and as a LAN switch with IGMP snooping in another area of the house.

---

I have set up two servers (Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS) in my network:

1. `Server A`: TeamSpeak and a few games
2. `Server B`:  Apache2, PHP, MySQL etc.

With my network setup (as mentioned above), I have managed to forward ports, so that friends can connect to `Server A` (be it TeamSpeak or the games), by forwarding the ports from `Router A` to `Router B` and then from `Router B` to the corresponding device (in this case `Server A`). Both servers and the second router each have a static IP address.

---

## The problem

Forwarding port 80 (and apparently some other ports, such as 21 and 22, too) to `Server B` leads to one of these results depending on whether the firewall of `Router B` is enabled:

1. **Firewall of `Router B` enabled:** The connection times out.
2. **Firewall of `Router B` disabled:** The connection is refused.

(Port-checking websites say that the port is closed in both cases.)

As the problem does not occur when I forward the port 80 of `Router A` to a device in `LAN A` (e.g. a laptop with XAMPP running), I suspect `Router B` (the *ASUS DSL-AC87VG* router) to cause this problem.

### Approaches

1. *I thought that the problem could be a result of a conflict with the web interface of `Router B`.* However, redirecting port 80 from `Router A` to another port of `Router B` (e.g. 38008) and then from this other port of `Router B` back to port 80 of `Server B` led to the same results. Also, "web access over WAN" (external access to the router's web interface) is disabled.
2. Updating the firmware of `Router B` did not solve the problem and the firmware of `Router A` is already up to date.
3. Although it is not recommendet, I also tried disabling DoS protection - without luck.
4. Disabling the firewall on `Server A` and/or `Server B` had no effect since the neccessary ports are already allowed by it.
5. Restarting both routers neither solved the problem.

Comment: Why are you double NATing? Is there a specific reason to have two networks and have the servers in the double NAT'd network? Would it not be much simpler to have one "big" subnet instead of two unique networks? Having two home grade routers back to back is generally a bad idea and usually causes lots of problems.

Comment: @acejavelin: I'm double NATing because of spatial reasons: The internet connection (and therefore `Router A`) is located in the living room. As mentioned, the WiFi signal of `Router A` is terrible on the other side of the flat, where `Router B` (as access point and switch) comes into play to supply the devices (including the servers which I don't want to have in the living room for acoustic reasons) on that side of the flat. But apart from that, the other port forwarding rules (e.g. for TeamSpeak) are working.

Comment: So why not just use router B as an extender... Disable DHCP, give it a static LAN IP of 192.168.2.2 and connect router A to a LAN port of B, essentially making it a switch, and router A handles all services for all devices. This is very common practice in home networks and many SOHO routers (like Asus RT series) have a mode like this built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @acejavelin, I have setup `Router B` as an extender by doing the following:

- Disable DHCP
- Assigning a static LAN IP near the one of `Router A` (like 192.168.X.2)
- Plugging the ethernet cable coming from `Router A` into a LAN port of `Router B` instead of the E-WAN port

This has solved the problem.